# Entire function with $|f(z^{2})|\leq e^{|z|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm stuck with this problem:

Suppose $f$ is entire, $f(k) = 0 \ $ for all$ \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $$|f(z^{2})|\leq e^{|z|}$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$ Then $f (z) = 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$

Any hint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality tells you that $f$ has an order of growth $\rho \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Then if $f \not \equiv 0$, and we index the nonzero zeros of $f$ by $z_1, z_2, \dots$, a standard theorem (See for instance Theorem 2.1 on Chapter 5 of Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi's Complex Analysis book) says that the sum

$$
\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|z_j|^s} < \infty
$$

for any $s>\rho$.

But this would produce a contradiction because we know that $f(k) = 0$ for any integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, since then for instance with $s = 1$, we would have

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|z_j|} < \infty
$$
Therefore $f \equiv 0$.